# Websphere Stuck on RenderPhase

Tags: java, jsf, websphere-7

We are having problem with WebSphere here in our company.

After 120 seconds the server is stoping execution with timeout, ok. This is the behavior expected after this delay.

The problem is that the SQL Query is taking about 30 seconds and after that the java thread 
stuck on jsf renderphase. Like we have set sleep() in the thread.

```
using a APM Tool (new relic)  the trace is:
 -MS-------%----CLASS-----------------------------------------
98200    79.11% LifecycleImpl.render(){      

----98200   79.11%  com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase/doPhase

-----874     0.70% our.service()

-----2.0     0.00% WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection()
-----37.0 0.03% SQL Database     29.012  s
-----94500  76.12% Application code (in com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase/doPhase)
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tX75I.jpg

The application stops for 94 seconds on renderphase until the timeout throw.

Seeing debug mode on chrome nothing happens on browser. Just stay in idle waiting the request. The JSF tree doesnt come to browser. (for me this means that the thread is stucking on container)
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/YURD5.gif

My `ManagedBean` implements `Serializable`

below the configuration:

1. Websphere 7.0 with cluster.
2. Java 1.6
3. Oracle 10g
4. JSF 1.2 Richfaces
5. Myfaces Majorra

Comment: WebSphere, JSF - there's your problem.  Why do people fall for that sham?

Comment: Yeah, we know. But we cant reinventing the wheel... :/

Comment: That's not a wheel.   That's a rack, an instrument of torture.

Comment: Here's a guess: JSF is killing you.  That's what your profiler says.   Why don't you believe it?

Comment: I'd start with that query.  There's no way a SQL query should take 30 seconds.  How many rows are you bringing back - millions?  That would explain it, too.

Comment: The query isnt bringing a lot of rows. To be more specific: 2400, but the business logic is on PL/SQL  what explain the 30 seconds.


The query indeed is a procedure.

Comment: About JSF killing me...i dont know...i think the problem is on websphere...

We have two cluster and a recent test (minutes ago) showed me that the thread dont stay stuck and the process ends in 40 seconds when the process is executing by a specific cluster (cluster two).

But the weird thing is: they have the same libs, only one difference the cluster one has more memory than cluster two. AND the problem occurs on cluster1

Comment: 30 seconds?  It's badly written.  No way that's required.

Comment: Maybe... . taking 30 seconds to  execute procedure is acceptable by user. What is not acceptable is the websphere put my thread to sleep with angels until timeout.


If a change the procedure call to a "select * form dual" nothing changes (i did it). The procedure doesnt matter right now. :/